# Datepicker: Setting input value to current date

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using this plugin for Bootstrap, for date picking http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/

I have it working here [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mP7mF/)
But I dont know if this is the right way to do it? Or if there's a way to do it through the plugin. I've tried to but I haven't got it right.

HTML:

```
Date: <input type="text" name="" class="datepicker" />
```

Jquery:

```
var d = new Date();

var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();

var output =((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month +  '/' + ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' + d.getFullYear();

$('.datepicker').datepicker();

$('.datepicker').val(output);
```

So I'm using Jquery to get the current date then I just fire the datepicker and then set the input value to the current date.

Any other ideas or suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: I don't see an issue with how you're doing it. I've had a quick look at the available options and methods for that datepicker and it doesn't look like you can set a default date.

Comment: I thought I was missing something, but looks like I'm not! Thanks @MarkWalters I'll just use this method.

Answer (score 4):

Your method is good.

You could, however, reduce it a couple of characters - if you'd like - to something like this:

```
var d = new Date(),
    output = [
        ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).substr(-2), 
        ('0' + d.getDate()).substr(-2), 
        d.getFullYear()
    ].join('/');

$('.datepicker').datepicker().val(output);
```

Also - if you're doing more work with dates - it might be a good idea to have a look at some date libraries, like [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) or [sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/dates), then you could do something like this:

```
$('.datepicker').val(new Date().toString('MM/dd/yyyy'));        // date.js
$('.datepicker').val(Date.create().format('{MM}/{dd}/{yyyy}')); // sugar.js
```

Comment: This looks great! I'll try this out and see how it works, it looks like it will reduce the amount of characters for getting the current date.

Answer (score 3):

Datepicker is initialized with current date by default. ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dd27v/))

You can set it manually too:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({defaultDate: new Date()}); //at initialization
$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate",new Date());      //runtume
```

Setting to other dates is easy too:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate","14/12/2014");
```

With self defined format:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-m-d" });
$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate","14-12-4");
```

To get that formatted value, use:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker().val();
```

[Documentation here.](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker)