# Set year of datepicker using jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, datepicker, uidatepicker

I am doing some work in .net technology using MVC 4.0 with VB language.

I have dropdownlist that has a set of years from 2006 to running year.
I want to set the selected year from dropdownlist to datepicker so I can have that year specific months and days and I have done following changes in datepicker.

```
 $('input').filter('.datepickerHoliday').datepicker({
                            changeMonth: true,
                            changeYear: false,
                            showYear: false,
                            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/' + yr,
                        });
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Where you want to display dropdown - inside your datepicker or outside. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865218/jquery-ui-datepicker-set-year-range-dropdown-to-100-years http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Comment: Dropdown is displayed outside. Actually I am taking year from dropdownlist and set it in datepicker (yr) as dateFormat but I am not getting the months and days for that specific year that I have selected in dropdownlist tht's why I have to set year in datepicker that I have selected in dropdown. How can I do that?

Comment: @MahavirsinhPadhiyar Are you using jQuery ui datepicker?

Comment: Yes I am using JQuery ui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do the trick. This is an basic you can build top of it.

```
var myDate = new Date();
var prettyDate = 01 + '/' + 01 + '/' + 'your selected dropdownlist year'
$("#date_pretty").val(prettyDate);
```

here is an link which gives you what you need :

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233553/how-do-i-pre-populate-a-jquery-datepicker-textbox-with-todays-date)

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964678/datepicker-setting-input-value-to-current-date)

Comment: No Vinod It's not working. Actually I am filtering all the textboxes that has datepicker class so last line might not work but still I have tried to do that by definig setDate but still not working. The months and days are coming of running year.

Comment: link is not redirect to a proper page.

Comment: Your link is helpfull and your code as well Vinod. I got what I want.

Answer (score 1):

```
var yr = $('#ddlYear').val();
var beforeDate = '01/01/' + yr;
var myDate = new Date(beforeDate);

$('input').filter('.datepicker').datepicker({
                   changeMonth: true
                   });
$('input').filter('.datepicker').datepicker("setDate", myDate);
```

so I got my selected year's date means year specific months and days.